# psql -U <user> does not work after created the role in pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have created a new role "joe" with pgadmin 4, it has a password, createdb rights, but not superuser privileges.

On Windows, using the terminal from visual studio code, I try to login as this user:
psql -U joe, it returns the following error (and I am sure of the password, I set up this new role):

```
$ psql -U joe
Password for user joe:
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "joe" does not exist
```

I have set PGUSER=postgres in my environment variables and if I just login with psql only it does prompt me for the password and works correctly but not with "joe".
Any recommendations to fix this?

Comment: Thanks @GolamrabbiAzad , found the answer within the responses provided in your link

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in the link provided by @GolamrabbiAzad

psql -U Username postgres # when you have no databases yet

Thanks